# Get top 1 row value from third table while joining 3 tables mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, join, stored-procedures

I am new to mssql .here I need to get some data using joins between three tables .

Header **join** Lines **join** Images --> Result

Header Table :

[image]

Line Table :

[image]

For each header record we can have multiple line items .

Images Table :

[image]

Each Image will have unique Image or multiple images .Need to get 1 image url from the list of items for the header record.

Result Set :

[image]

Query :

```
SELECT HT.O_ID,
       HT.Type,
       HT.Total,
       IM.Image 

FROM HEADER_TABLE HT 

JOIN LINE_ITEM_TABLE LIT 
ON LIT.O_ID = HT.O_ID 

JOIN IMAGE_TABLE IT 
ON IT.IMAGE = LIT.ITEM_ID 

WHERE IT.SECTION = 'Retail'
```

This query returns multiple rows .But I need one unique row for each Header record.

Can anyone help me to fix .

Comment: Hi and welcome to DBA.SE! The table create + insert statements could be useful to get an answer faster. (Testing purposes)

Comment: *I need one unique row for each Header record.* If so you MUST to build a criteria which will say what record from all record pack with the same header must be returned.

Comment: Can you check and possibly update a couple of things in your question?  Your SQL statement as currently written should return no rows; the second join needs to say `on IT.ITEM_ID = LIT.ITEM_ID`.  Also, the sample data that you've included doesn't show any duplicates on the ITEM_ID field, so it doesn't look like the query (with the corrected join) would have any duplicates either.  Are there actually multiple rows per Item ID in that table?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to `SELECT` just the `TOP 1` image from each particular header. `APPLY` is similar to a function you can create "on the go" that links columns or expressions from outside to it's filters or joins.

```
SELECT
    -- Header columns:
    HT.O_ID,
    HT.Type,
    HT.Total,

    -- Columns from the CROSS APPLY result
    I.Image
FROM 
    HEADER_TABLE HT 
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 -- Just retrieve 1 row (for each HT row)
            IT.IMAGE
        FROM
            LINE_ITEM_TABLE LIT
            INNER JOIN IMAGE_TABLE IT ON IT.ITEM_ID = LIT.ITEM_ID
        WHERE
            LIT.O_ID = HT.O_ID AND  -- Link the outmost header "HT" record to it's lines "LIT"
            IT.SECTION = 'Retail') AS I
```

You can add an `ORDER BY` inside the `CROSS APPLY` to determine which image will get selected. You can also change the `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY` if you want header rows to display even when there is no matching record coming from the `APPLY` operator (the `IMAGE` column will be `NULL`).

Answer (score 3):

> But I need one unique row for each Header record.

To me it is unclear if you mean one unique record per `HT.O_ID` or no duplicate records regarding all the four columns returned.

If it is the latter, add the `DISTINCT` keyword to your query (and add the schema names).

```
 SELECT DISTINCT HT.O_ID,
           HT.Type,
           HT.Total,
           IT.Image 

    FROM dbo.HEADER_TABLE HT 
    JOIN dbo.LINE_ITEM_TABLE LIT 
    ON LIT.O_ID = HT.O_ID 
    JOIN dbo.IMAGE_TABLE IT 
    ON IT.Item_ID = LIT.ITEM_ID 
    WHERE IT.SECTION = 'Retail';
```

**Result**

```
O_ID    Type    Total   Image
1001    Online  $10 URL
```

**If that does not solve it**

Then you would have to group by the values in the `Header_Table` And decide which `Image` you need to keep,do concatenation on it, ....

```
SELECT HT.O_ID,
       HT.Type,
       HT.Total,
       MAX(IT.Image) as MaxURL

FROM dbo.HEADER_TABLE HT 
JOIN dbo.LINE_ITEM_TABLE LIT 
ON LIT.O_ID = HT.O_ID 
JOIN dbo.IMAGE_TABLE IT 
ON IT.Item_ID = LIT.ITEM_ID 
WHERE IT.SECTION = 'Retail'
GROUP BY HT.O_ID,HT.Type,HT.Total;
```

---

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HEADER_TABLE(O_ID int,Type varchar(100),Total varchar(10))
INSERT INTO dbo.HEADER_TABLE(O_ID,Type,Total)
VALUES  (1001,'Online','$10');

CREATE TABLE dbo.LINE_ITEM_TABLE(ID int,O_ID int,Item_ID varchar(4),Line_Total varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.LINE_ITEM_TABLE(ID,O_ID,Item_ID,Line_Total)
VALUES  (1,1001,'P001','$2'),
        (2,1001,'P002','$2'),
        (3,1001,'P003','$2'),
        (4,1001,'P004','$2'),
        (5,1001,'P005','$2');


CREATE TABLE dbo.IMAGE_TABLE(Item_ID varchar(10),Image varchar(100),Section varchar(10))
INSERT INTO dbo.IMAGE_TABLE 
VALUES  ('P001','URL','Retail'),
        ('P002','URL','Retail'),
        ('P003','URL','Stock'),
        ('P004','URL','Retail'),
        ('P005','URL','Retail');
```